# Does fetch-API ReadableStream work with promise.then(...)?

Tags: javascript, promise, stream, fetch-api

I'm trying to use the [Fetch API readable streams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams) to download multiple files.

```
const files = [.....]; // my file objects
const promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i += 1) {
  const file = files[i];
  promises.push(
    fetch(file.uri)
    .then(response => {
      const reader = response.body.getReader();

      return new ReadableStream({
        async start(controller) {
          while (true) {
            const { done, value } = await reader.read();
            // When no more data needs to be consumed, break the reading
            if (done) {
              break;
            }

            if (!file.content) {
              file.content = value;
            }
            else {
              file.content += value;
            }
            // Enqueue the next data chunk into our target stream
            controller.enqueue(value);
          }
          // Close the stream
          controller.close();
          reader.releaseLock();
        }
      });
    })
    .then(rs => new Response(rs))
  );
}
return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  // do something else once all the files are downloaded
  console.log('All file content downloaded');
});
```

The idea here is for the file objects to only have a URI. Then this code will add a content field. After this point I can do something else.

However, in practice, the code sequence is incorrect. Namely the following lines run immediately after each other.

```
return new ReadableStream({...});
console.log('All file content downloaded');
```

The code's not waiting until the file content has been downloaded. The log above is printed ahead of time. After it runs I see the code hit the

```
while (true) {
```

Loop's code. i.e. Where the file content is streamed.

I'm obviously misunderstanding a fundamental concept. How can I wait for the file content to be downloaded and **then** do something else? i.e. How do streams work with the promise.then() model.

Comment: Yes, this is how I would expect your code to behave. 

Promise.all returns when all all promises in the Array resolve. When you return the readable stream, it resolves the promise. The async line inside the ReadableStream is not part of the promise.all chain, and does not come into consideration here.

Comment: I assumed the ReadableStream object would act as a promise on my behalf? I also thought await was, under the covers, promised based meaning it should interleave with a promise chain without issue?

Comment: You can make Await and Async part of the promise chain, but in this example that's not what's happening. Same goes for regular promises. The only way to make them part of the chain is to return them in a `.then` block. not in a returned object that, itself, returns a promise. that's outside of the chain.

Comment: That makes sense. Though I'm have trouble seeing how I'd do that with ReadableStream. I'd being assuming that's what controller.enqueue(value); was meant to do.

Comment: In looking for a quick resource to help, I found a cool npm package just for this: 

https://github.com/dex4er/js-promise-readable

Comment: The benefit of the fetch API is its support for promises. 'Feels' like I should not require a separate module to use it with promises.

Comment: you're absolutely right. Fetch is Promise based, but the returned items are not promises. They are expected to be returned in a .then of the fetch.

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream

This package just helps you wrap that in a promise to help make things easier, it's not required at all.

Comment: I don't think it's sinking. Might need to sleep on it. Don't understand how that example knows when the site has finished streaming. Only thought I have now is to check if the reader object should be returned instead of the stream object.

Comment: a readable stream is just that, a stream. You're not really expected to know when it's 'done', instead you implement a stream reader. ( I assume that npm lib I sent is able to know when it's 'done', which would prove very useful, but I don't know that lib at all so that's just an assumption. ) see: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/getReader

`reader.read().then` will be particularly useful to you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the simplest solution was to create my own promise.

```
const files = [.....]; // my file objects
const promises = [];
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i += 1) {
  const file = files[i];
  promises.push(
    fetch(file.uri)
    .then(response => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = response.body.getReader();
        const stream = new ReadableStream({
          async start(controller) {
            while (true) {
              const { done, value } = await reader.read();
              // When no more data needs to be consumed, break the reading
              if (done) {
                break;
              }

              if (!file.content) {
                file.content = value;
              }
              else {
                file.content += value;
              }
              // Enqueue the next data chunk into our target stream
              controller.enqueue(value);
            }
            // Close the stream
            controller.close();
            reader.releaseLock();
          }
        });
      });
    })
    .then(rs => new Response(rs))
  );
}
return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  // do something else once all the files are downloaded
  console.log('All file content downloaded');
});
```

Caveat: The error scenario should also be gracefully handled.

Comment: By chance I came across an article that confirms the above - https://javascript.info/promise-chaining